# fill list with attribute value and compare another attribute value from xsl using xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My XML is:

```
<root>
<emps>
<emp id="1" name="alpha" city="tt" />
<emp id="2" name="beta" city="pp" />
<emp id="3" name="gamma" city="tt" />
</emps>
</root>
```

and I want to fill combo list with all the employees where city='tt'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you outputing HTML here? Could you show us a sample of the code you are expecting to be output. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,and I got it woking,I posted it quickly coz it was high Priority task.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please post the answer below and accept it so that people will know it was answered.

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe,and I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <select>
 <xsl:for-each select="root/emps/emp[@city='tt']">                                                                                                                                      

        <option >                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>                                                                                                                                        

       </option> 
        </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
```

this is an answer for the query on attribute selection.